# Is Isolation Forest a Distance-Based Model?

Tags: scikit-learn, scikits

I know five standard unsupervised outlier detection approaches :

- Probabilistic models
- Clustering-based models
- Distance-based models
- Density-based models
- Time series outlier detection models

But what type is Isolation Forest? According to google it is a ''tree-based model'', but is it also possible to say that isolation forest is a Distance-based model?

Answer (score 2):

While the [Anomaly detection's wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) states that it is a `Density-based technique`, you should instead refer to [the original paper](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/icdm08b.pdf?q=isolation-forest), and Scikit-learn documentation.

`Isolation forest` is indeed useful for anomaly detection, and is particularly efficient for large datasets. It is represented by a tree structure, and given that it uses `recursive partitioning`,
*`the number of splittings required to isolate a sample is equivalent to the path length from the root node to the terminating node.`*

In addition to all the details provided in the [Scikit-learn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#isolation-forest), you can read in the [source paper](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/icdm08b.pdf?q=isolation-forest):

> Apart from the key difference of isolation versus profiling, iForest is distinguished from existing model-based, distance-based and density-based methods in the following ways:

> 1. The isolation characteristic of iTrees enables them to
>    build partial models and exploit sub-sampling to an
>    extent that is not feasible in existing methods. Since
>    a large part of an iTree that isolates normal points is
>    not needed for anomaly detection; it does not need to
>    be constructed. A small sample size produces better
>    iTrees because the swamping and masking effects are
>    reduced.

> 2. iForest utilizes no distance or density measures to detect anomalies. This eliminates major computational
>    cost of distance calculation in all distance-based methods and density-based methods.

> 3. iForest has a linear time complexity with a low
>    constant and a low memory requirement. To our
>    best knowledge, the best-performing existing method
>    achieves only approximate linear time complexity with
>    high memory usage.

> 4. iForest has the capacity to scale up to handle extremely
>    large data size and high-dimensional problems with a
>    large number of irrelevant attributes.

Comment: The answer is not completely distance-based, due to being *Invariant to the choice of distance metric (since it doesn’t use a distance metric in the first place)* and it is mainly a **randomized partitioning/splitting-based process recursively**. check this [reference](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/isotree/vignettes/An_Introduction_to_Isolation_Forests.html#Overview)